# Why does my shell process recieve SIGTTOU after its child dies

Tags: linux, shell, unix, rust, tty

I am trying to write a shell in Rust. I am taking the following steps to execute a foreground job:

- I am kicking off the new child in its own process group
- I am handing the new child the terminal (tcsetpgrp)
- I am waiting for the child to finish
- I am (attempting to) take the terminal back (tcsetpgrp)
- I am (attempting to) reset the terminal attributes

My shell process hangs immediately after the shell exits. It is catching SIGTTOU repeatedly with no end.

Here is the minimal reproducible example I was able to derive from my code.
Bash here is used as an example child process launched from my shell.

```rust
extern crate signal_hook;
extern crate nix;

use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use signal_hook::{consts, iterator::Signals};
use std::os::unix::process::CommandExt;
use std::thread::spawn;
use nix::{unistd, unistd::Pid, sys::termios::{tcgetattr, tcsetattr, SetArg}};

fn main() {
    // setup signal handlers
    let signals = Signals::new([
        /* glibc says to block SIGCHLD but since I already have a backgroun thread
         * it seems like a perfect way to know when background jobs have stopped...
         */
        consts::SIGINT, consts::SIGQUIT, //consts::SIGCHLD,
        consts::SIGTSTP, consts::SIGTTOU, consts::SIGTTIN,
    ]);
    if let Err(e) = signals {
        println!("couldn't spawn signal handler: {}", e);
        return
    }
    spawn(move || {
        for sig in signals.unwrap().forever() {
            println!("Received signal {:?}", sig);
        }
    });

    let parent_pid = unistd::getpid();
    let attr = tcgetattr(0).unwrap();

    let term_owner = unistd::tcgetpgrp(0).unwrap();
    let parent_pgid = unistd::getpgid(Some(parent_pid)).unwrap();
    if parent_pgid != term_owner {
        nix::sys::signal::kill(
            term_owner,
            nix::sys::signal::Signal::SIGTTIN,
        ).expect("cant seize terminal");
    }

    if parent_pid != parent_pgid {
        unistd::setpgid(parent_pid, parent_pid).unwrap()
    }

    unistd::tcsetpgrp(0, parent_pid).unwrap();

    // kick off child process in its own PG
    let mut chldproc = Command::new("/bin/bash")
        .stdin(Stdio::inherit())
        .stdout(Stdio::inherit())
        .stderr(Stdio::inherit())
        .process_group(0)
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();

    let pid = chldproc.id();
    unistd::setpgid(
        Pid::from_raw(pid as i32),
        Pid::from_raw(pid as i32),
    ).unwrap();

    // give child terminal
    unistd::tcsetpgrp(
        0, Pid::from_raw((chldproc.id() as i32).into()),
    ).unwrap();

    // cant use i.wait() because it closes stdin
    loop {
        if let Ok(maybe) = chldproc.try_wait() {
            if let Some(_) = maybe {
                unistd::tcsetpgrp(0, parent_pid).unwrap();
                tcsetattr(0, SetArg::TCSADRAIN, &attr).ok();
                break;
            }
        } else {
            panic!()
        }
    }

    println!("finished successfully!");
}
```

I expect that after the child exits the parent is able to take the terminal back, and reset the attributes.

Instead the program hangs immediately after exiting bash. I get an infinite sea of "Received signal 22".